# Regex validate for 3 digits and two decimals with a decimal point

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I am currently using this Regex: `^\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,2})?$` as was supplied in the question here :
[Regex for up to 3 whole numbers and 2 decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52119739/regex-for-up-to-3-whole-numbers-and-2-decimals)

This works fine in a regex tester and does match the pattern.
The issue I am having is when validating an input and preventing anything other than 3 digits and 2 decimals is that the pattern does not allow for 3 digits and a decimal, before the 2 decimal digits, e.g.

`234.34` is allowed

`234.` is not allowed

I cannot type anything after the decimal currently as it is prevented based on the pattern. I would like to enter a decimal after the three digits and it match along with the 2 digits after the decimal and it not match less than 1 e.g.

```
allowed

1
2.
2.3
2.38
22.
22.2
22.38
234. 
234.2 
234.34 

not allowed

0.2
0.23
00.23
000.23
234.255
```

Comment: Try this: `^[1-9](?:\d{1,2})?\.?(?:\d{1,2})?$` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kt8trr/2)

Comment: Something like [`^[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:\.\d{0,2})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/bsoI0a/1) will work. But the comment below by @apokryfos seems to be very appropriate in your case!

Comment: If you mean you want to validate as you type, then do not prevent invalid input but rather provide feedback to the user that the current input is invalid but still allow them to continue input. Only prevent the submission of an invalid input

Comment: I didn't think of it like this, many thanks this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly you are validating while typing. Just signal the user if it is ok or not.  Next snippet checks the given input while typing, signals the user and it sets a data-attribute (`data-ok=0/1`) on the input that may be used for further processing. It uses [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) for `keyup` and `change` handling.

```js
document.addEventListener(`keyup`, handle);
document.addEventListener(`change`, handle);

function handle(evt) {
  if (/nr|numeric/i.test(evt.target.id)) {
    let rawVal = evt.target.value.trim().replace(/,/, `.`);
    const checked = document.querySelector(evt.target.dataset.checker)
    
    if (!rawVal) {
      checked.textContent = ``;
      return checked.classList.remove(`ok`);
    }
    
    const [min, max] = evt.target.dataset.minmax.split(`,`).map(Number);
    rawVal = parseFloat(rawVal);
    const cando = !isNaN(rawVal) && rawVal >= min && rawVal <= max;
    checked.textContent = cando 
      ? `${rawVal} OK!` : `${rawVal || evt.target.value} NOT OK`;
    checked.classList[cando ? `add` : `remove`](`ok`);
    evt.target.dataset.ok = +cando;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font: normal 12px/15px verdana, arial;
  margin: 2em;
}

#check, #checknr {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#check.ok, #checknr.ok {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="nr" 
  placeholder=">= 0 and < 1000"
  data-minmax="0,1000"
  data-checker="#check"> enter number (max 1000)
<span id="check"></span>

<p>
  You may also check the possibility of using
  <a target="_blank" 
    href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number"
  >numeric input</a>
  <input type="number" id="numeric" 
    data-minmax="0,1000"
    min="0" 
    max="999.99" 
    step="0.1"
    placeholder="0 - 999.99"
    data-checker="#checknr">
    
    <span id="checknr"></span>
</p>
```